# Load Binary Formatter file in Universal app

Tags: c#, serialization, win-universal-app, binaryformatter

I have an application build with .NET 4.0 and I want to port this application to a Windows 10 application.

In the old application I saved my data to a binary file using Binary Formatter.

```
using (FileStream fs2 = File.Create(serializationFile))
            {
                var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

                bformatter.Serialize(fs2, transactionData);
            }
```

With the following class that is serialized:

```
    [Serializable]
public class TransactionData
{
    public TransactionData()
    {

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TransactionCategory> TransactionCategories { get; set; }
    public List<TransactionMonth> TransactionMonths { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to load that files in my Universal App.

The problem is the following are not working:

```
[Serializable]
```

and:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters
```

Is it possible to load this files in Universal App? And if so, how can it be done?

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is very sensitive to framework differences, you really should not be using it for persistent storage, it really is only intended for IPC between AppDomains on the same machine. Either use a Xml formatter or use a 3rd party PCL compatible library if you want to stick to binary.

Comment: Universal apps target a much smaller version of the .NET Framework, the kind that fits mobile devices.  Making it smaller required cutting features, BinaryFormatter was one that fell on the floor.  So no, you don't have any use for your existing data files as-is.