# Will Binary Serialization work on a web/mobile apps?

Tags: c#, serialization

Basically the title, I have an average grasp on binary serialization to the local machine in C# now and was wondering if that would work and was good enough to use with web and mobile games or if I should learn something else for that medium.

Comment: Say I wanted to make a mobile game and save someone's progress to their phone

Comment: If by "Binary Serialization" you mean *Serialization by `BinaryFormatter`*, then be aware that [`BinaryFormatter` is only available on the full, standard .Net platform.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).  Unlike, say, [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), it's not present on Windows Universal, Windows Phone, or the PCLs.  See [Load Binary Formatter file in Universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976167).

Answer (score 2):

Binary serialization is going to introduce coupling between components. Your client and server would need to be using the exact same classes. I can't see any benefit to that. You could have a client that has no idea what to do with a serialized .NET class. Without knowing more specifics I'd lean toward JSON.

If the client and server are both .NET, they can still serialize and deserialize classes using data passed as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Binary serialization will work fine with c#. Writing a Windows phone app, binary serialization will be fine.

When your using code bases in other mobile and web technologies, text based serialization especially JSON will be much easier to work with.